# Ethernet Bandwidth

Tags: ethernet

I am measuring some 100 Mbps and 1Gbps device's bandwidth using Iperf 2.0.
the values I am getting are 91 Mbps(for 100 Mbps devices) and 890 Mbps(for 1 Gbps Devices). is this normal? what range do such devices usually get?

Comment: Do you know what exactly iperf is measuring?

Comment: its sending data from client to server and measuring the bandwidth of it.

Comment: So you don't know what exactly it is measuring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, those numbers look pretty good — payload throughput that's ~90% of the raw wire speed is quite typical for Ethernet.

The other 10% is consumed by Ethernet and TCP/UDP/IP overhead.